# Help getting a representation of a curve K for a Line integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

So I have to calculate line integral of a vector field:
$\overrightarrow{F}(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z,x+y)$

And I want to calculate the Line integral:

$$\int_K \overrightarrow{F}(x,y,z)d\overrightarrow{r}$$

And K is defined as intercutting of these two surfaces: 
$$x^2+y^2=1, z=x^2+y^2-2y$$

I did do a sketch, and is seems like it some sort of elipse or circle.

But how can I get its equation?

I thougth maybe something like this this:

$x^2=1-y^2 \rightarrow z=1- y^2+y^2-2y=-2y $

But it just gave me normal line, or is this all there is to it?

Are there any tricks to it. 
Any help with the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: $z=1-2y$ is correct.

Comment: How do I apply it in the integral? Should I make a parametrization and how?

Comment: What is the argument of the integral? the dot product (circulation) or variation over the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You wish to integrate over the set 
\begin{align}
K &= \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 =1 \quad \text{and} \quad z = x^2 + y^2 - 2y  \} \\
&= \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 =1 \quad \text{and} \quad z = 1 - 2y  \} \tag{$*$}
\end{align} 
Notice that if you now define the function $\alpha: [0,2 \pi] \to \Bbb{R}^3$ by the rule
\begin{equation}
\alpha(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(t) \\
\sin(t) \\
1 - 2 \sin(t)
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
then $K = \text{image}(\alpha)$. In words, $\alpha$ is a parametrization for $K$. I hope you see how I obtained such a parametrization from ($*$). Hence,
\begin{align}
\int_K \vec{F}(x,y,z) \cdot d \vec{r} &= \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\vec{F}(\alpha(t)) \cdot \dfrac{d \alpha}{dt} \right) \, dt
\end{align}

(the $\cdot$ being a dot product of vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$)
I'll let you substitute the formulas and perform the computation. I got $-3 \pi$ as the answer... there may/may not have been a computation error, but this is the general process of how to approach these questions.